# Grunt watch config option "reload: true" doesn't pick up changes

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

My setup has a `Gruntfile.js` that loads tasks from individual files, one being `all_sass.js`. I want to have `grunt watch` running, make changes to `all_sass.js`, and see those changes in effect without having to stop/start `grunt watch` manually.

As I have it now, the terminal tells me that grunt watch can "see" when I change `all_sass.js`:

```
OK
>> File "grunt/tasks/all_sass.js" changed.
```

But it doesn't actually reload the task or restart grunt watch. It continues to run with the same behavior, on the same files it was initially watching.

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            configFiles: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'grunt/tasks/*.js'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Load all tasks from the grunt/tasks folder
    grunt.loadTasks('grunt/tasks');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['allSass']);
};
```

**grunt/tasks/all_sass.js:**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var scssPath = 'dest/scss';
    var cssPath = 'dest/css';

    // Config
    grunt.config.set('allSass', {
        scssPath: scssPath,
        cssPath: cssPath
    });

    // sass
    grunt.config.set('sass.allSass', {
        options: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= allSass.scssPath %>',
            src: ['**/*.scss'],
            dest: '<%= allSass.cssPath %>',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    });

    // watch
    grunt.config.set('watch.allSass', {
        files: ['<%= allSass.scssPath %>/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['allSass'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('allSass', 'Compile sass', [
        'sass:allSass'
    ]);
};
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?